# Spring bean configuration list<map>

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Im trying to create a bean configuration file for my 
`SettingsDto` class:

```
public class SettingsDto {
    private String administratorEmail;
    private String gatekeeperAddress;
    private String webRtcUrl;
    private String userGuideUrl;
    private String vmrFaqUrl;
    private String lyncGuideUrl;
    List<Map<String, String>> supportPhones;
    List<String> audioCalls;
```

But Im having issues with how Im doing the supportPhones (`List<Map<String, String>>`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="sandbox.spring" />

    <bean id="SettingsBean" class="com.dto.SettingsDto">

        <property name="administratorEmail" value="v@.com" />
        <property name="gatekeeperAddress" value="192.168.1.0" />
        <property name="webRtcUrl" value="https://web.com" />
        <property name="userGuideUrl"
            value="url" />
        <property name="vmrFaqUrl"
            value="url" />
        <property name="lyncGuideUrl"
            value="url" />

        <property name="audioCalls">
            <util:list>
                <value>+1 (000)000-0000</value>
                <value>(000)000-0000</value>
            </util:list>
        </property>



    <property name="supportPhones">
        <util:list>
            <ref bean="supportPhonesMapping1" />
            <ref bean="supportPhonesMapping2" />
        </util:list>
    </property>

    <util:map id="supportPhonesMapping1">
        <entry key="name" value="North America" />
        <entry key="phone" value-ref="+1 111-1111" />
    </util:map>
    <util:map id="supportPhonesMapping2">
        <entry key="name" value="+11 111-1111" />
        <entry key="phone" value-ref="International" />
    </util:map>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The error I get is

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'util:map'. No child
>   element is expected at this point

Comment: You should be using java based configuration at this point, it's much easier for things like this.

Comment: And at least using a recent version of Spring; 3.0 is several years old.

Comment: I have tried a few different variations, including implementations with just giving the schema location for 'beans' but still the same issue.  as well as updating 'bean' to 3.0

Comment: @EngineerDollery not sure i understand your comment as spring beans are very "Java".  what do you suggest for what im doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set value to `util:map` that way. `value` can only take a string. Define a `util:map` separately, then use `ref` to reference it.

For example:

```
<util:map id="myMap">
  <entry key="name" value="..." />
</util:map>

<util:list>
  <ref bean="myMap"/>
</util:list>
```

Also, `value-ref` should reference another bean - currently you have it as a string literal value, which you can simply use `value` for.

Comment: hi, i believe this is the proper solution but its still not working for me.  please see my edits above and comment on anything you still see wrong.

Comment: I see, you mean that the map has to be declared outside the `<bean>` definition, not inside it?

Comment: yes you should declare util:map outside of your `SettingsBean`

Comment: @user2264997 if you want to make mention that my syntax "value-ref" was wrong as well as suggesting it be removed from the bean definition (defined outside of the bean).  Ill mark yours as the answer, since it helped me the most

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your beans schema. You have it slightly wrong. It should be:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

Comment: actually, from a maintenance standpoint it's best to leave off version info in the schema declarations. Spring will pickup the highest available.

Answer (score 0):

so in the end there were a few issues.

first off my declaration was wrong

```
    <entry key="phone" value-ref="International" />
```

needed to be

```
    <entry key="phone" value="International" />
```

(no "-ref")

I also changed the xml to define my list and map outside of the bean then referenced it in the bean

```
    <property name="supportPhones" ref="supportPhoneList" />
```